# How would I find the 3 x 3 elementary matrices A and B such that the respective matrix equations hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

(i) $$A * \begin{pmatrix}-4&1&3\\ 4&1&2\\ 1&-5&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-4&1&3\\ 8&2&4\\ 1&-5&1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$B * \begin{pmatrix}-4&1&3\\ 8&2&4\\ 1&-5&1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-4&1&3\\ 4&1&2\\ 1&-5&1\end{pmatrix}$$

(ii) $$A * \begin{pmatrix}-5&5&4\\ 1&-4&4\\ -5&2&5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-4&4\\ -5&5&4\\ -5&2&5\end{pmatrix}$$

$$B * \begin{pmatrix}1&-4&4\\ -5&5&4\\ -5&2&5\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-5&5&4\\ 1&-4&4\\ -5&2&5\end{pmatrix}$$

(iii) $$A * \begin{pmatrix}2&5&-1\\ -5&-4&-2\\ -3&1&5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2&5&-1\\ 1&11&-5\\ -3&1&5\end{pmatrix}$$

$$B * \begin{pmatrix}2&5&-1\\ 1&11&-5\\ -3&1&5\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2&5&-1\\ -5&-4&-2\\ -3&1&5\end{pmatrix}$$

I tried to find the inverse of the matrix on the right of the "=" sign but kept getting the wrong answer. I thought that was how we solve for unknowns in matrix equations.

Any help?

Comment: i) $A= \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&2&0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ check and continue...the second matrix B is easy...$B= \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&{\frac 1 2}&0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ you have to try to find the other ones.

Comment: To keep the same line in the matrice you use a line like that in the identity matrice...with zeros and a single 1 ....Then in the second line you needed to multiply the second line taht explain the 2 in the middle

Comment: ii) $A=B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$  can you check if that works ? For the second question ii) ? @Dev ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have managed to solve them now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: that's great ...you don't really need inverse matrices here...

Comment: As you have now solved them, let me encourage you to write up & post your solutions.

Comment: Today would be a good day, Dev.